# How to get list of modified fields when using GWT Editor?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Need to get list of modified fields. List of strings or widgets (like combos, textfields, etc) are acceptable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`EditorVisitor`s](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/client/EditorVisitor.html), you can capture the original values just after your call to `edit()` and then visit the editors at any later time to compute the changed fields.

Actually, this is exactly what the editor framework does internally to compute [`isDirty()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/client/EditorDriver.html#isDirty()), so you can possibly copy/paste code from GWT directly.

Comment: Is there an option to make it in a more generic way? Cause I really don't want to write tons of stuff like (.visit(textfield1), . visit (textfield99), etc) .

Comment: It **is** generic. Write a couple of `EditorVisitor`s and pass them to [`EditorDriver#accept()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/client/EditorDriver.html#accept%28com.google.gwt.editor.client.EditorVisitor%29) when needed. I slightly reworded my answer to make it clearer I was talking about an existing API and not just the concept of visitors.

Comment: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/2.7.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/editor/client/impl/DirtCollector.java collects each leaf editors' value. You could copy the code, call it twice and compare results.